# Remove underscore for column names

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using this Linq query to display columns in my gridview.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings ["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CS);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "ManLog_Profits";
        adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        adapter.Fill(dt1);
        var query = from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    where r.Field<string>("Department") == "Manufacturing"
                    select new
                    {
                        ID = r["ID"].ToString(),
                        Dep_Name = r["Dep Name"].ToString(),
                        Sales_Profit = r["Sales Profit"].ToString(),
                        Sales_Transport = r["Sales Transport"].ToString  (),                            
                    };
        GridView1.DataSource = query;
        GridView1.DataBind();
}
}
```

Now how could I possibly remove the underscore for my column names.

Comment: Are you doing any manipulations in your gridview like add, edit, delete & update?

Comment: @Learner - The gridview is readonly and I'm not performing any manipulations.

Comment: Then probably its good you handle in aspx page so that you can make the gridview looking good by making your custom design changes. Just add ItemTemplate and put a label inside each tag which will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your linq query your using anonymous type. You can decide for the name yourself

```
select new
{
  ID = r["ID"].ToString(),
  DepName = r["Dep Name"].ToString(),
  SalesProfit = r["Sales Profit"].ToString(),
  SalesTransport = r["Sales Transport"].ToString()
};
```

Comment: The problem is I want to include spave between words for my columns.

Answer (score 0):

Set the columns manualy - `AutoGenerateColumns = false`:

```
GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
GridView1.Columns.Add(new BoundField() { HeaderText = "ID", DataField = "ID" });
GridView1.Columns.Add(new BoundField() { HeaderText = "Dep Name", DataField = "Dep_Name" });
GridView1.Columns.Add(new BoundField() { HeaderText = "Sales Profit", DataField = "Sales_Profit" });
GridView1.Columns.Add(new BoundField() { HeaderText = "Sales Transport", DataField = "Sales_Transport" });

GridView1.DataBind();
```

you can also use DataView.Filter instead Linq query:

```
DataView dv = new DataView() {Table = dt};
dv.Filter = "[Department] = 'Manufacturing'"
GridView1.DataSource = dv;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I am not able to get that HeaderText method. It says object doesn't contain definition for header text.

Comment: I know I can handle this in aspx. Since I have used in many pages just looking for a simple solution where I can replace underscore with ana empty space.

Comment: @Vicky you right (also because you can not access Auto-Genereted Column), i edited my answer.